# stacking columns in data.frame into one column in R

Tags: r, dataframe, reshape

I'm having trouble stacking columns in a data.frame into one column. 
Now my data looks something like this:

```
id   time    black   white   red 
a     1       b1      w1     r1
a     2       b2      w2     r2
a     3       b3      w3     r3
b     1       b4      w4     r4
b     2       b5      w5     r5
b     3       b6      w6     r6
```

I'm trying to transform the data.frame so that it looks like this:

```
id   time  colour 
a     1     b1
a     2     b2
a     3     b3
b     1     b4
b     2     b5
b     3     b6
a     1     w1
a     2     w2
a     3     w3
b     1     w4
b     2     w5
b     3     w6
a     1     r1
a     2     r2
.     .     .
.     .     .
.     .     .
```

I'm guessing that this problem requires using the reshape package, but I'm not exactly sure how to use it to stack multiple columns under one column. Can anyone provide help on this?

Comment: Have you looked at the  help for `melt` in the `reshape` (or more uptodate `reshape2` package.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here's melt from reshape:

```
library(reshape)
melt(x, id.vars=c('id', 'time'),var='color')
```

---

And using  `reshape2` (an up-to-date, faster version of `reshape`)  the syntax is almost identical.

The help files have useful examples (see `?melt` and the link to `melt.data.frame`).

In your case, something like the following will work (assuming your data.frame is called `DF`)

```
library(reshape2)
melt(DF, id.var = c('id','time'), variable.name = 'colour')
```

Comment: Related question: is there a way to use melt.data.frame to stack all columns of a data.frame? Does setting id.vars=c() work?

Comment: @gvrocha Indeed it does.  Note that supplying `c()` is different from not supplying the option.  See the "Details" section of `?melt`.

Answer (score 10):

Since you mention "stacking" in your title, you can also look at the `stack` function in base R:

```
cbind(mydf[1:2], stack(mydf[3:5]))
#    id time values   ind
# 1   a    1     b1 black
# 2   a    2     b2 black
# 3   a    3     b3 black
# 4   b    1     b4 black
# 5   b    2     b5 black
# 6   b    3     b6 black
# 7   a    1     w1 white
# 8   a    2     w2 white
# 9   a    3     w3 white
# 10  b    1     w4 white
# 11  b    2     w5 white
# 12  b    3     w6 white
# 13  a    1     r1   red
# 14  a    2     r2   red
# 15  a    3     r3   red
# 16  b    1     r4   red
# 17  b    2     r5   red
# 18  b    3     r6   red
```

If the values in the "black", "white", and "red" columns are `factor`s, you'll need to convert them to `character` values first.

```
cbind(mydf[1:2], stack(lapply(mydf[3:5], as.character)))
```

Comment: I needed to stack all columns into a 2-col dataframe and your solution works. Thanks.